# Python NLTK Wordnet Issue

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, synonym, augmentor

Code Used

```
augmenter = naw.SynonymAug(aug_src='wordnet', model_path=None, name='Synonym_Aug', aug_min=1, aug_max=10, aug_p=0.3, lang='eng', 
                         stopwords=stop_words, tokenizer=None, reverse_tokenizer=None, stopwords_regex=None, force_reload=False, verbose=0)

augmenter.augment("What is random swap")
```

Getting the error

```
Resource 'corpora/wordnet' not found.  Please use the NLTK
  Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

I've done everything- Updated the package, reinstalled this even checked this in corpora folder within nltk_data. Nothing is working. Same error comes again and again. Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly.

Referred many documentation on this error which mostly talked about issue with the directory path or wordnet not being there. But these also did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Error explains that you have installed nltk package but you've not downloaded 'wordnet' since you're using it in the code.

1. Open python console

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('wordnet')
```

and it will work .

OR

2. In your code file:

```
import nltk

# Set the download directory
nltk.download('wordnet', download_dir='/path/to/download/directory')
```

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned, I tried following this approach. I rechecked the files present in nltk_data/corpora. I can see wordnet.zip there. Maybe the issue is because file is not unzipped. Can you or members of this community please let me know how to unzip a file in python environment (not terminal). I'm using kaggle note book for scripting and the loaction is 'user/share/nltk_data/'  which has the following libraries- taggers
stemmers
corpora
grammars
models
sentiment
chunkers
tokenizers
help          Wordnet.zip is present in corpora and I need to unzip this.